# Difference in input values using cin.get from file and manual

Tags: c++, file-io, input

I was writing some code that needs to take values one by one and store them into a 2D int array, and was having differences when taking values from file and manually inputting them.  It looks like this :

```
int ar[9][9];
while(!cin.eof()){
  for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<9; j++)
    {
      cin.get(temp);
      ar[i][j] = temp -48;
    }
}
```

I would pass in input from the terminal running it like

```
./prog.out < inp.txt
```

and get the value of -38 for a random value like ar[0][1], but i would get the correct value when I type

```
./prog.out
12345678 ^d
```

getting 2 when printing ar[0][1], which is correct.  Why should this code be acting differently?  Is it because the file is the full 81 characters followed by \n and eof, compared to just a couple values followed by ^d?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of `temp` variable?

Comment: Its a char, sorry for not including

Comment: Did you check that you're really entering the loop when you're redirecting "inp.txt"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not checking `eof` at the right time - it's set when an attempt to read a value hit eof, not beforehand - so the behaviour's a bit random. And, you're assuming that not being at eof means you can read 81 values... how do you know you weren't one newline away from `eof`? And you're not checking the success of `cin.get()`....

I recommend simply

```
for(...)
    for(...)
        if (cin.get(temp))
            ar[i][j] = temp - '0';
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "insufficient input\n";
            exit(1);
        }
```